# Get nginx version synchronously?

Tags: bash, nginx

Something weird is going on when I try to get the nginx version.

When I run this command:

```
echo "[nginx]" $(nginx -v)
```

It prints

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
[nginx]
```

Notice the `[nginx]` bit is *below* the nginx version.

When I try with Node OTOH, `echo "[node]" $(node --version)`, I get:

```
[node] v0.10.45
```

Which is in the expected order, so it's not a problem with echo. How can I get nginx to print in the proper order?

Not sure if this is a Bash/shell issue or something funny with the nginx program or what.

Comment: More good solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62271695/sed-command-isnt-working-to-extract-the-nginx-version-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Who knows why the decision was made, [but nginx outputs to stderr](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/592). You can capture it by piping stderr to stdout:

```
echo "[nginx]" $(nginx -v 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to pipe it to a format string you could do:

```
$(nginx -v) | printf "[nginx] "
```

or even...

```
nginx -v | printf "[nginx]%1s"
```