# Get the web server version in PHP

Tags: php, server

I would like the version of a web server (Nginx, MySQL, MariaDB, ...) in PHP.

I know the function for Apache: `apache_get_version()`.
There are many `phpinfo()` which returns all values but how to exploit?

You would have an idea or it is not possible for the moment?

Comment: Note that `apache_get_version()` only retrieves Apache's version, not the other services the system might be running; each of them requires a different way to retrieve their values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `shell_exec` would do the trick (assuming you're on a unix based server). Just don't put any user data into the command, and be aware that this approach may not work in shared hosting environments:

```
$nginxVersion = shell_exec('nginx -v 2>&1');
$mysqlVersion = shell_exec('mysql --version');
```

Note that [nginx sends version output to stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821075/get-nginx-version-synchronously/38821121#38821121), so you need to pipe it to stdout to capture it.

Comment: Dangerous, but it works... if you're not inside a container/jail/virtual machine, that is.

Comment: Oh, and besides dangerous and taking account of all the limitations shown on the answer, it _also_ requires that you know _which_ web server you're running in order to retrieve its version...

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the web server's version by using the $_SERVER superglobal, more specifically by using:

```
 $_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE']
```

As per PHPs Documentation:

> **SERVER_SIGNATURE**
>
> String containing the server version and virtual host name which are added to server-generated pages, if enabled.

You can find more info on the official PHP Documentation site:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Clearly this is _the_ best answer — it's correct, it's to the point, it doesn't require one to know in advance what web server is being run (unlike the accepted answer), and it works across all possible combinations of platforms and operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Address the $_SERVER super-global http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

I believe the setting you want is:

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This time, $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] for me only for the web server.

Comment: This just gives the server _hostname_ (if set and available) and even that might not be relevant in many cases (since it can be easily forged). `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` does _not_ include any information whatsoever for the _web_ server (i.e. Apache, nginx, lighthttp, Caddy...), but rather only for the _machine_ (and just its hostname) that is running the web service.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers mention different methods on how to get the web server and database versions, however there is a function which will get the operating system itself.

```
// Gets the "System" row shown at the top of the `phpinfo()` table.
$system = php_uname( $mode = 'a' );
```

You can specify the mode to select different components. By default it'll display all of the components, separated by spaces and in the following order:

- s: Operating System Name
- n: Host name
- r: Release Name
- v: Version Information
- m: Machine Type

[You can view more information about the `php_uname` function here.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php)

Comment: That's really interesting, especially since there are so many completely different OS calls to accomplish what `php_uname()` apparently does effortlessly — unify all of them under a common API! Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

To query the version of MySQL and/or MariaDB in PHP, you could use [mysqli_get_server_info()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-server-info.php) or (if you are still using the older mysql API which was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and removed in PHP 7.0.0) [mysql_get_server_info()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-get-server-info.php). The PDO API has no similar function or class for that purpose, but in that case you could just use the result of the SQL query

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

It returns something like `5.5.50-0+deb7u2`. Here's a quick example:

```
<?php
  $user = 'username_here';
  $pass = 'your_db_password';
  // create DB connection
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysql', $user, $pass);
  $stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT VERSION();');
  //fetch first column of first result row and print it out
  echo $stmt->fetchColumn();
  //unset PDOStatement and PDO to close DB connection
  unset($stmt);
  unset($dbh);
?>
```

Comment: That's just for the database version, _if_ it uses MySQL.

Comment: ... incidentally, if you're reading this after 2020 or so, the deprecated API mentioned on the answer has been definitely _removed_, so... if you can still use it (which you shouldn't!), complain to your system administrator, because you happen to be running a way too old version of PHP! 

Comment: @Gwyneth Llewelyn: Regarding the "if it uses MySQL" comment: The question explicitly mentions MySQL and the accepted answer also uses MySQL. So I guess that's fine. Besides, this also works with MariaDB or any other DBMS that is compatible to MySQL. And as far as the deprecated/removed API is concerned, I've just added the PHP versions numbers for when the old mysql API was deprecated and removed. But the PDO API which is used in the code snippet is neither deprecated nor removed, it worked back in 2016 and it still works today with modern PHP versions. So there is not really a problem here.