# How to use sed to extract Nginx version number (only) from output string?

Tags: shell, sed

I'm stuck with a weird situation: I'm trying to extract the version of nginx with sed, but it does not working, only the string version works:

```
[root@hostname~]# echo $(nginx -v) | sed -n 's/nginx version: nginx\///p'
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1

[root@hostname~]# nginx -v | sed -n 's/nginx version: nginx\///p'
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1

[root@hostname~]# echo 'nginx version: nginx/1.16.1' | sed -n 's/nginx version: nginx\///p'
1.16.1
```

Any clues?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821075/get-nginx-version-synchronously a duplicate?

Comment: Hello! That's a similar question, but the answers provided here are more detailled than in the other one.

Comment: If it is the same question (asking for the same technique) then the most appropriate Stack Overflow action would be to close this page as a duplicate and then add the "better" advice to the earlier posted page.  This best helps future researchers by putting more "good eggs" in fewer "baskets". After all, that's actually the point: "help future researchers" as opposed to just bloating this site with more content.

Comment: Also tangentially read about [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
nginx -v |& sed 's/nginx version: nginx\///'
```

or even shorter/simpler:

```
nginx -v |& grep -oP '/\K.*'
```

Or for POSIX shell:

```
nginx -v 2>&1 | sed 's/nginx version: nginx\///'
```

The `|&` part is a classic *pipe* but redirecting `STDERR` to `STDOUT` with the special `&` trick.

**Because `nginx -v` output on the error output, aka `STDERR`.**

Comment: Very interesting, that's why it works for other commands like netstat, but not for nginx.

Comment: Absolutely, yes. STDERR STDIN & STDOUT are things to know in shell programing

Answer (score 1):

```
nginx -v 2>&1 | cut -d'/' -f2
```

Comment: What is the `cut` command and what do these parameters mean?

Comment: Just type `man cut` in your shell window (or google `shell cut` or `cut man page`) and that'll be extremely clear. This is a UNIX shell question and `cut` is one of the standard UNIX tools, just like `sed` and `grep` used in the question and the other answers posted here but much, MUCH simpler.

Comment: Is there a way to catch if nginx does not exist / is not installed?

Comment: @ShivanandSharma Yes, post a question asking about that.